# How should be implemented the RequiresAuthentication annotation for multiple web roles?

Tags: java, authentication, struts2, annotations, security

I'm developing an *Struts2* with *Hibernate* web application. I'am reading the book [*Practical Apache Struts 2 web 2.0 projects, by Ian Roughley*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599039). 
In that book, the author shows 3 ways to make the authentication to access web resources: *Container Based*, using *Acegi* library, and a *Custom* mode.

So, my app has at least 3 modes, and the actions must be accessed depending on this.

I take the custom mode, because it is the best suited for me (considering I'm developing with *Struts2*).

The custom mode uses a `SecurityInterceptor` and a `SecureStack` for the *struts.xml* actions. The authentication works when there is added a `@RequiresAuthentication` annotation in the top of the action class that I want to provide restriction.

Here is the definition of the `RequiresAuthentication` annotation given by the book:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiresAuthentication {
}
```

So the author left clear that if more complex role-based security is required,
the annotation could be enhanced to specify the roles that are allowed to invoke the action.
So I want to know how should this annotation be implemented for 3 modes or more.

Comment: "So I want to know how should this annotation be implemented for 3 modes or more." -  You mean you want multiple means of security in a single application or do you just mean by "three modes" that there is three or more roles ("manager", "admin", "user", etc.)

Comment: Yes, I mean 3 roles or more, like "admin", "client", "client_rg"

Comment: I would look at the roles interceptor and then use the same annotations provided for use by that interceptor (although you would write your own interceptor to provide the required authentication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So add some variables to your custom annotation (e.g. roles) and check it values in your interceptor.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiresAuthentication {
   public String[] roles();
}
```

BUT you really should consider using some security framework (e.g. Spring Security, Apache Shiro) instead of your custom solution.

Comment: For use Spring Security my app has to use The complete Spring framework or it is not necessary?

Comment: Spring framework consists of modules. You have to use only modules that are needed.